# T_PUBLIC, expecting T_STRING using require()

Tags: php, require

I am getting an error when I link to my functions via `require()`

error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC, expecting T_STRING in /home/content/23/9953123/html/new/lib/functions.php on line 3`

code:

```
<?php
require("lib/functions.php");
require("lib/dbconnect.php");
?>
```

functions.php:

```
<?php

function stateToAbb($input){ 
//reset found 
$found = 0; 
//list states 
$states = "Alaska,Alabama,Arkansas,Arizona,California,Colorado,Connecticut,Delaware,Florida,Georgia,Hawaii,Iowa,Idaho,Illinois,Indiana,Kansas,Kentucky,Louisiana,Massachusetts,Maryland,Maine,Michigan,Minnesota,Missouri,Mississippi,Montana,North Carolina,North Dakota,Nebraska,New Hampshire,New Jersey,New Mexico,Nevada,New York,Ohio,Oklahoma,Oregon,Pennsylvania,Rhode Island,South Carolina,South Dakota,Tennessee,Texas,Utah,Virginia,Vermont,Washington,Wisconsin,West Virginia,Wyoming"; 
//list abbreviations 
$abb = "AK,AL,AR,AZ,CA,CO,CT,DE,FL,GA,HI,IA,ID,IL,IN,KS,KY,LA,MA,MD,ME,MI,MN,MO,MS,MT,NC,ND,NE,NH,NJ,NM,NV,NY,OH,OK,OR,PA,RI,SC,SD,TN,TX,UT,VA,VT,WA,WI,WV,WY"; 
//create arrays 
$states_array = explode(",", $states); 
$abb_array = explode(",", $abb); 

//run test 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($states_array); $i++){ 
    if (strtolower($input) == strtolower($states_array[$i])){ 
        $found = 1; 
        $output = $abb_array[$i]; 
        return $output; 
    } 
} 
if ($found != 1){ 
    $output = $input; 
    return $output; 
} 
return $output; 
} 

?>
```

But when I just put the function in the file with out require a separate php file for it, it works just fine...

Any ideas?

UPDATE...

Since everyone thinks I am trying to pull a fast one and use different code...
Here is an updated code...

```
<?php
require("lib/functions.php");
require("lib/dbconnect.php");
function stateToAbb($input) { 
    //reset found 
    $found = 0; 
    //list states 
    $states = "Alaska,Alabama,Arkansas,Arizona,California,Colorado,Connecticut,Delaware,Florida,Georgia,Hawaii,Iowa,Idaho,Illinois,Indiana,Kansas,Kentucky,Louisiana,Massachusetts,Maryland,Maine,Michigan,Minnesota,Missouri,Mississippi,Montana,North Carolina,North Dakota,Nebraska,New Hampshire,New Jersey,New Mexico,Nevada,New York,Ohio,Oklahoma,Oregon,Pennsylvania,Rhode Island,South Carolina,South Dakota,Tennessee,Texas,Utah,Virginia,Vermont,Washington,Wisconsin,West Virginia,Wyoming"; 
//list abbreviations 
$abb = "AK,AL,AR,AZ,CA,CO,CT,DE,FL,GA,HI,IA,ID,IL,IN,KS,KY,LA,MA,MD,ME,MI,MN,MO,MS,MT,NC,ND,NE,NH,NJ,NM,NV,NY,OH,OK,OR,PA,RI,SC,SD,TN,TX,UT,VA,VT,WA,WI,WV,WY"; 
//create arrays 
$states_array = explode(",", $states); 
$abb_array = explode(",", $abb); 

//run test 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($states_array); $i++){ 
    if (strtolower($input) == strtolower($states_array[$i])){ 
        $found = 1; 
        $output = $abb_array[$i]; 
        return $output; 
    } 
} 
if ($found != 1){ 
    $output = $input; 
    return $output; 
} 
return $output; 
} 
?>
```

It does not work...when I remove `require("lib/functions.php");` it works so the issue is with that line of code

Comment: 1. SO is not your personal parser 2. I believe you show us different file

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code shown, try posting the other file.

Comment: I just guess: You have a `public function foobar() { /* code */ }` somewhere outside a class. Thats not possible, not allowed and beside this it even doesn't make much sense :D

Comment: updated with full portion of the php at the top, if I remove `require("lib/functions.php");` page loads fine, and the above text is all that is in the `functions.php` file

Comment: Are you sure you are showing us the correct file? I note your path includes `html/new/` perhaps you're looking at 'html/old'?

Comment: no this is the correct file, all that you are looking at is all I have...I also tried removing `require("lib/dbconnect.php");` but it doesn't make any difference

Comment: Why the downvotes, it is a legitimate question?

Comment: I think people are downvoting because the error suggests that line 3 is `public function stateToAbb($input){ ` but your file is showing differently. It's unlikely that PHP is incorrectly showing that message.

Comment: @AlexLunix `function stateToAbb($input){ ` I believe.

Comment: @Jim Exactly :) I doubt, that this is the real code, because: http://codepad.viper-7.com/F6Nd0J It works even with PHP5.2

Comment: Yes line 3 in index.php is `require("lib/dbconnect.php");` however when removed it still does not work...and line 3 in functions.php is `function stateToAbb($input) { `

Comment: @KingCrunch, this is the code, like I said when I just use the php code in functions.php within index.php and I replace `require("lib/functions.php");` with that code, it works...it is an issue with the code `require("lib/functions.php");`

Comment: Okay updating question so people dont think I am an idiot

Comment: Thanks for nothing guys...it got closed

Comment: @ChrisJamesChampeau Since you updated your question with interesting information, it got reopened, as shown on [the revision page](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14368106/revisions).

Comment: Please show use line 3 of functions.php, it says the error is in functions.php, I think that's where the confusion is. The reason it fails is because functions.php has an error in it.

Comment: I was able to solve it, I deleted the file and started fresh...it seemed to solve it, and I was getting errors from my FTP when I tried to delete it so I am not sure if it was corrupt or what, but after deleting the functions.php file, and re-typing the above funciton, it now works...no idea why or how

Answer (score 1):

The first step in debugging this: Change something to see if the error message changes as well.

I always make sure I am looking at the right file by adding a blank line somewhere before the error line. If the error message changes accordingly, I know I have the correct file.

After that, depending on which error message I have, I probably insert `die()` if the code crashes. For parsing errors, adding semikolons at some places might help.

To nail down the exact location of the error in a line, I usually split every keyword in this line onto a line of its own. Whitespace is no problem for parsing, but doing this allows for better identification of where exactly the parser complains.